# How to reach a Windows machine by hostname?

Tags: 10.10, networking, windows

I have always been under the impression that all I need to do in order to reach the Windows machines on my network by their hostnames from Ubuntu was do add the '**wins**' option to the 'hosts' line in my **/etc/nsswitch.conf** file, but since I installed Maverick (from RC iso, new install) that doesn't work anymore.

My system is currently configured with the following line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4 wins
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by access? Do you mean remote desktop, file sharing, etc?

Comment: Now that you ask, I see I wasn't much clear on that. I actually mean just pinging.

Comment: You only want WINS if you're dealing with pre-XP machines. `avahi-client` (installed by defalt IIRC) will do name resolution otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sooo... It seems all I had to do was install the *winbind* package, contrary to some Google knowledge stating it's only needed for authentication.

Maybe winbind was part of the standard desktop installation and dropped from the Maverick CD?